# AnyLogic: stop Delay for a specific agent in the delay block

Tags: delay, anylogic, agent

In my process, I have a delay block with unlimited capacity. The agents in the delay block are only freed if stopDelay() is called.

If an event occurs, I want to stop the delay for some of the agents stored in this delay block.
However, I only want to free the x (can vary) agents, which have been in the block for the longest time.
Is there a function/trick for that or do I have to compare the "getElapsedTime(Agent agent)" for all agents in the delay block manually?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend replacing the `Delay` block with a `Wait` block. You can also give it unlimited capacity. Instead of using stopDelay(), use free().

Your code would look something like that (where x is the number of agents you want to go through):

```
int x = 0;

x = 3;

for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++) {
wait.free(wait.get(i));
}
```

Also, make sure to replace `wait` in the code with the wait block's name.